# Given two extensions of $\left| \cdot \right|_p$ to $\Bbb{C}$, do the subsets of elements of absolute value $1$ coincide?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

It is known that $\Bbb{C}$ is isomorphic as a field to $\Bbb{C}_p$, the completion of $\bar{\Bbb{Q}}_p$ with respect to $\left|\cdot\right|_p$. Clearly, given two such isomorphisms $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ we can define extensions $\left|\cdot\right|_{p,i} = \left|\varphi_i(\cdot)\right|_p$ of $\left|\cdot\right|_p$ from $\Bbb{Q}$ to $\Bbb{C}$.

Now, I don't expect those two extensions to be equivalent -- especially since I couldn't find any reference for this -- but **I've been wondering if the sets**
$$
U_i := \left\{ x \in \Bbb{C} : \left|x\right|_{p,i} = 1 \right\}
$$
**coincide**.

---

I'm very new to p-adic analysis, but I think it should be the case. In his book *A course in p-adic analysis* Alain Robert proves that there is a group isomorphism
$$
\begin{align}
\psi \colon \Bbb{C}_p^{\times} &\simeq p^{\Bbb{Q}} \times U \\
x = r \cdot \frac{x}{r} &\mapsto (\left|r\right|_p, \frac{x}{r})
\end{align}
$$
where $U := \left\{ x \in \Bbb{C}_p : \left|x\right|_p = 1 \right\}$ and $r$ is an element of $p^{\Bbb{Q}} \hookrightarrow \Bbb{C}_p^{\times}$ (after a choice of embedding). In particular the composition
$$
\Phi \colon p^{\Bbb{Q}} \times U \xrightarrow{\psi^{-1}}
\Bbb{C}_p^{\times} \xrightarrow{\varphi_1^{-1}}
\Bbb{C}^{\times} \xrightarrow{\varphi_2}
\Bbb{C}_p^{\times} \xrightarrow{\psi}
p^{\Bbb{Q}} \times U
$$
is a group automorphism. Now suppose that $U_1 \neq U_2$. Then wlog we can find an $x \in U_1$ such that $\left|\varphi_2(x)\right|_p \neq 1$, which means that $\psi(\phi_1(x)) = (1,\phi_1(x))$ and $\Phi(\psi(\phi_1(x))) = (p^q,u)$ with $q \neq 0$. But this is absurd because $\Phi$ restricted to $p^{\Bbb{Q}}$ is a group automorphism.

*Remark:* Since it wasn't clear, here by "restriction of $\Phi$ to $p^{\Bbb{Q}}$" I actually mean the restriction of $\Phi$ to $p^{\Bbb{Q}} \times \{1\}$ composed with the canonical isomorphism $p^{\Bbb{Q}} \times \{1\} \simeq p^{\Bbb{Q}}$.

*Is this argument correct? If so, is there a simpler one?*

Comment: $(1,\varphi_1(x))\notin p^{\Bbb Q}$, so how do you apply your "restriction to $p^{\Bbb Q}$" argument?

Comment: My impulse is to say that your conjecture must be false, but I’m having a lot of trouble understanding precisely what the conjecture *is*. What would constitute a counterexample?

Comment: Rotation by an angle $\alpha$ is an automorphism $r_\alpha$ of the additive group $\Bbb R^2=\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$. Can you write $r_\alpha$ as $(\tau_1,\tau_2)$? Mind that $r_\alpha(0,1)=(\cos\alpha,-\sin\alpha)$.

Comment: @Lubin A counterexample would be given by two non-equivalent extensions $\left|\cdot\right|_{p,1},\left|\cdot\right|_{p,2}$ of $\left|\cdot\right|_p$ from $\Bbb{Q}$ to $\Bbb{C}$ and an element in $\Bbb{C}$ such that $\left|x\right|_{p,1} = 1$ but $\left|x\right|_{p,2} \neq 1$. Equivalently, it would be given by two isomorphisms $\varphi_1,\varphi_2\colon \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}_p$ and an element $x \in \Bbb{C}$ such that $\left|\varphi_1(x)\right|_p = 1$ but $\left|\varphi_2(x)\right|_p \neq 1$.

Comment: My problem with constructing an explicit counterexample is that an isomorphism between $\Bbb{C}$ and $\Bbb{C}_p$ are defined in terms of a bijection between a transcendence basis of $\Bbb{C}$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ and a transcendence basis of $\Bbb{C}_p$ over $\Bbb{Q}_p$ (so it's a bit unwieldy).

Comment: @AdLibitum I edited with a simpler remark addressing your concern.

Comment: @A.P. you still fail to address the fact that $(1,\varphi_1(x))\notin p^{\Bbb Q}\times 1$ and thus you cannot apply the "restriction to $p^{\Bbb Q}$" to that element. Have you noticed my comment about the rotation in $\Bbb R^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s your counterexample, with $p=2$. Your element of $\Bbb C$ is $(1+\sqrt{-7})/2$, one chosen root $\alpha$ of $X^2-X+2$. Since this polynomial becomes $X^2+X=X(X+1)$ over $\Bbb F_2$, it splits over the $2$-adic integers $\Bbb Z_2$, by Hensel. That is, in $\Bbb Q_2$, one root is a unit (has $2$-absolute value $1$), the other is a nonunit (has $2$-absolute value less than $1$). Now, any isomorphism from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb C_p$ must take $\alpha$ to one of the roots in $\Bbb Q_p$ of $X^2-X+2$. Clearly, there are some that take $\alpha$ to the unit root, some that take $\alpha$ to the nonunit root.

Comment: I see: I was under the impression that there is a canonical way to embed $\Bbb{Q}_p$ into $\Bbb{C}$, but apparently I was wrong.

Comment: Yep, there’s a canonical way to embed $\Bbb Q$ into $\Bbb C$, but since the topologies are so different, once you go up to $\Bbb Q_p$, things get torn apart. That is, things close in $\Bbb Q_p$ can not be expected to have close images in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: That much I knew. The thing is that I thought that the canonical embedding of $\Bbb{Q}$ into $\Bbb{C}$ extended to $\Bbb{Q}_p$. Now I see that it isn't the case, much like there are multiple ways to embed an algebraic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ into $\Bbb{C}$ (which is essentially what you are using here).

Comment: By the way (off topic): "emeritus" doesn't mean "depleted (or devoid) of merit" but "due to merit". So if someone is a "professor emeritus" it doesn't mean he is worn out by his duties, but that he has earned the right to be called "professor" even if he isn't exercising the profession anymore -- even on a literal, etymological sense. ;)

Comment: Of course I knew the real meaning of “emeritus”: my Latin dictionary has it as a noun meaning “veteran”. But I think the fictional definition is much more fun.